# Spring+Hibernate+postgres error : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0 (unable to load class org.postgresql.Driver)

Tags: postgresql, java-8, spring-3, hibernate3

I am running a sample **Spring 3.2+Hibernate+Postgres 9.4 on Apache tomcat8** java-8 web application. I am getting following error:

> **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:** Error
>   creating bean with name 'employeeDao': Injection of autowired
>   dependencies failed; nested exception is
>   **org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException**: Could not
>   autowire field: private org.hibernate.SessionFactory
>   com.forum.dao.EmployeeDaoImpl.sessionFactory; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: 
>   Cannot resolve reference to
>   bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested
>   exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml]: Error setting property values;
>   nested exception is:
>   org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException; nested
>   PropertyAccessExceptions (1) are: PropertyAccessException 1:
>   org.springframework.beans.MethodInvocationException: Property
>   'driverClassName' threw exception; nested exception is
>   **java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/postgresql/Driver**
>   **Unsupported major.minor version 52.0** (unable to load class
>   org.postgresql.Driver)

**database.properties file in src/resources**

```
database.driver=org.postgresql.Driver
database.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/sample
database.user=postgres
database.password=sujata
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=update
```

**spring-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-   3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

<context:property-placeholder   location="classpath:resources/database.properties" />


<context:component-scan base-package="com.forum" />
    <mvc:annotation-driven/>

<tx:annotation-driven transaction-   manager="hibernateTransactionManager"/>

<bean id="jspViewResolver"
      class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass"
        value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>


<bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${database.driver}" />
    <property name="url" value="${database.url}" />
    <property name="username" value="${database.user}" />
    <property name="password" value="${database.password}" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="annotatedClasses">
        <list>
            <value>com.forum.model.Employee</value>

        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}  </prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>             
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="hibernateTransactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />
</bean>
```

I have tried all the available answers - checked my JRE, JDK compliance level, postgres version and associated driver, dialect name, proper driver. But the issue persists. Also the program runs perfectly for Mysql. I have put postgresql-9.4-1206-jdbc42.jar in Web Content/WEB-INF/lib/ folder and not included it in the build path via Add External Jars. What is wrong in following definitions?

Comment: You have any entries in error logs ?

Comment: Apache Tomcat8/logs folder is empty.

Comment: With what version of the JDK are you _building_ and _running_ Tomcat?

Comment: java version "1.8.0_66"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_66-b17)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.66-b17, mixed mode)

Comment: Did you type `java -version` from a command prompt to get this output?  In other words, are you _certain_ that Tomcat is running on JDK 8?

Comment: Thankyou so much. Tomcat was running on java-7. I changed it. Now it is working. :)